# Как сделать такую подложку для яндекс карты?

Tags: яндекс-карты

как сделать такую подложку + была возможность интерактива карты?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чисто технически - можно накинуть CSS фильтр на слой карты, но я не знаю как на это смотрит сам Яндекс, боюсь это против правил, по-этому я и не пользуюсь ими никогда, кроме случаев когда нужна именно они.

```js
ymaps.ready(() => {

    let yMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [60, 30.3],
        zoom: 11
    })

    yMap.controls.add('zoomControl');

    yMap.geoObjects.add(new ymaps.GeoObject({
        geometry: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [60, 30.3]
        }
    }));
    
});
```

```css
.ymaps-layers-pane {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}

#map {
  width:400px; 
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.standard,package.geoObjects&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Grayscale добавил, только там просят что бы была вот эта подложка черная с прозрачностью, таким же образом пробовал и не получается...